# How to load multiple fixture sets for the same model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures

While I usually prefer Factory Girl, I am in the need of using existing fixtures to test an application I am working on.

The problem is that I need to use test-dependent sets of fixture, ie I have multiple sets for the same model that need to be loaded depending on which test I am running.

In the old days of rails 0.x there were a couple of plugins to do that. How do I accomplish the same with Rails 3+?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894781/multiple-fixture-sets-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

You can create some script file which call your factories to create records.  Then require the scripts in your tests.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide such scripts as an example to start with.

Comment: Thought this example would be obvious.
FactoryGirl.create(:model1)
FactoryGirl.create(:model2, :attr1 => FactoryGirl.create(:model3))

Answer (score 0):

You say you are a fan of Factory Girl, so I don't have to sell you on how awesome it is.

Why not convert those fixtures to factories? [Convert Fixtures into Factory Girl in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445584/convert-fixtures-into-factory-girl-in-rails) should be of assistance.

Once you have your data as factories in Factory Girl, I recommend that you take advantage of its inheritance features as shown in https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md:

> You can easily create multiple factories for the same class without repeating common attributes by nesting factories:

```
factory :post do
  title "A title"

  factory :approved_post do
    approved true
  end
end

approved_post = FactoryGirl.create(:approved_post)
approved_post.title    # => "A title"
approved_post.approved # => true
```

> You can also assign the parent explicitly:

```
factory :post do
  title "A title"
end

factory :approved_post, parent: :post do
  approved true
end
```

Comment: Hi James and tanks for the time spent in drafting the answer. Nevertheless, the question is how to load test-specific fixtures and not how to use Factory Girl to replace the fixtures. As said, I appreciated the advantages of Factory Girl in several projects but lately I prefer to use the fixtures.